# How to filter out developer profiles from provisioning profiles in ipad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4

How to filter out developer profiles from provisioning profiles, so that we can keep track of provisioning profiles in ipad..???

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you meant, but the simplest solution would be to follow proper naming conventions.

PS: Be more clear in what you want to ask here.